# R RFE function not working on a different data set

Tags: r, rfe

```
rfeResults1 <- rfe(galaxySmall_DFSample[, 1:58], 
                       galaxySmall_DFSample$galaxysentiment, 
                       sizes=(1:58), 
                       rfeControl=ctrl)
```

Error Message:

> Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = cuts)) : 
>     missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you have NAs in your data frame? If so, please remove the NAs first then run the analysis.